# why "SomeType globalVar = cast(SomeType) import("path/to/file")" does not work?

Tags: d

as the title says why

```
SomeType globalVar = cast(SomeType) import("path/to/file")
```

does not work? and result to
`` cannot cast `"..."` to `SomeType` at compile time ``

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There may be many reasons for this. [`import` expressions](https://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#import_expressions) creates a string literal. Does `cast(SomeType)"some other string"` compile? If so, is the text in `/path/to/file` a valid string for `SomeType` to be created from? Does `SomeType` have an appropriate constructor that takes a string?

This code compiles:

```
struct S {
    this(string s) {}
}

S globalS = cast(S)"foo";
```

Removing `S`' constructor produces the error message you describe. This makes me think that `SomeType` does not have a constructor with the appropriate signature, but it's hard to say without knowing more of your code and the contents of the file you're importing.

Comment: I was trying to embed a Font into my program but it seems like D doesn't allow to cast to my Font Struct at compile time and I have to cast the pointer at runtime

Answer (score 1):

It will work if `SomeType` is the right type.

The result of `import("some/path")` is a `string`. You cannot cast a `string` to a `struct`. But in your case, it's probably binary data, not an actual text file.
What you can do is the following:

```d
// Load the file and convert it to `immutable(ubyte[])`
immutable ubyte[] manifestBinaryData = cast(immutable ubyte[]) import("path/to/file");

// Safety check, you can even add an error message with expected and actual size
static assert(manifestBinaryData.length >= SomeType.sizeof);

// Equivalent to a reinterpret_cast in C++. The compiler will not check anything.
immutable SomeType* myFont = cast(immutable SomeType*) manifestBinaryData.ptr;
```

You can do smarter things: e.g. you could parse / process the data at compile time if you want. But the above snippet is, I believe, the closest to your intentions.

Comment: doesn't work. ```reinterpreting cast from immutable(ubyte)* to immutable(Font!(...))* is not supported in CTFE ```

Comment: Uh that's unfortunate. Then your best chance is to implement a function that deserializes your `Font` struct.